# What do these GParted instructions mean?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I just successfully shrank my Windows partition using GParted to make room for a shared data partition for both Ubuntu and Windows. It warned me:

[image: Screenshot of GParted's warning after I used GParted to successfully shrink the Windows 7 partition]

What do instructions 1 and 3 mean? I didn't know I had a choice of what sector of the hard drive to make the new partition. And what is the "new NTFS filesystem size"? Isn't that just the size of the partition I'm making?

Comment: Were you using gparted, or Windows own Disk Management app? I hope it was the latter. Cheers, Al

Comment: @heynnema Windows would only shrink it by 3MB when I had 70GB free

Comment: You're not being clear. Edit your question and please post a screenshot of gparted. Cheers, Al

Comment: @heynnema edited

Comment: I'm sorry. I meant a gparted screenshot of your hard disk /dev/sda. The part that confuses me is "Windows would only shrink it by 3mb when I had 70G free". You should always manage NTFS partitions using Windows own Disk Management app, not gparted. Cheers, Al